# Modifying file content using filename

Tags: bash, sed

Excuse my english...

I need to modify content of a bunch of xml files, changing a string by the filename without the '.xml' extension.

Example for file FOO_3786.xml :

Before...

```
\<SOME STUFF\>...\</SOME STUFF\>

\<FILENAME\>FOO_1\</FILENAME\>

\<SOME OTHER STUFF\>...\</SOME OTHER STUFF\>
```

After...

```
\<SOME STUFF\>...\</SOME STUFF\>

\<FILENAME\>FOO_3786\</FILENAME\>

\<SOME OTHER STUFF\>...\</SOME OTHER STUFF\>
```

I am trying to do it with `find` and `sed` commands, but I fail to automate the replacement of old filename by current filename without the '.xml' extension. It seems to be the wrong way.

Actually, my command is:

```
find . -type f -name "\*.xml" -exec sed -E 's@\<FILENAME\>FOO\_\[\[:digit:\]\]+\</FILENAME\>@\<FILENAME\>{}\</FILENAME\>@g' ;
```

I hoped `{}` would be understood as filename. But I get a missing parameter message for -exec.

Comment: Use an XML-specific tool like `xmlstarlet` rather than `sed`.

Comment: Transforming (editing) xml documents to produce other xml documents is a good job for XSLT. Saxonica is a great product for doing that.

Comment: @Barmar, thx, but unfortunately, xmlstarlet is not installed on the server, and the admin will not do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using xslt. Strip off the xml extension then use it as a `--stringparam` with `xsltproc`.

```sh
for f in *.xml; do
    xsltproc -o out/"$f" --stringparam filename "${f%.*}" filename.xsl "$f"
done
```

Use the identity transform pattern in `filename.xsl`:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!-- pass the filename as a stringparam -->
<xsl:param name="filename" />

<!-- copy everything ... -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- ... except for the element you want to change -->
<xsl:template match="FILENAME">
    <FILENAME><xsl:value-of select="$filename"/></FILENAME>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thx, I will try this solution, and write back how I succed.